# Using Task Parallel Library do handle frequent URL requests

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am using .Net to build a stock quote updater. Suppose there are X number of stock symbols to be updated during market hours. in order to keep the updating at a pace not exceeding data provider's limit (e.g. Yahoo finance), I will try to limit the number of requests/sec by using a mechanism similar to thread pool. Let's say I want to allow only 5 requests/sec, that corresponds to a pool of 5 threads.

I heard about TPL and would like to use it although I am inexperienced of it. How can I specify the number of threads in the implicitly used pool in Task? Here is a loop to schedule the requests where requestFunc(url) is the function to update quotes. I like to get some comments or suggestions from the experts to do it properly:

```
// X is a number much bigger than 5
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i=0; i<X; i++)
{
    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { requestFunc(url); }, TaskCreationOptions.None);
    t.Wait(100); //slow down 100 ms. I am not sure if this is the right thing to do
    tasks.Add(t);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Ok, I added a outer loop to make it run continuously. When I make some changes of @steve16351 's code, it only loops once. Why????

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LimitedExecutionRateTaskScheduler scheduler = new LimitedExecutionRateTaskScheduler(5);
        TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(scheduler);
        List<string> symbolsToCheck = new List<string>() { "GOOG", "AAPL", "MSFT", "AGIO", "MNK", "SPY", "EBAY", "INTC" };


        while (true)
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            Console.WriteLine("Starting...");

            foreach (string symbol in symbolsToCheck)
            {
                Task t = factory.StartNew(() => { write(symbol); },
                                                                     CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler);
                tasks.Add(t);
            }
            //Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            Console.WriteLine("Ending...");
            Console.Read();
        }

        //Console.Read();
    }

    public static void write (string symbol)
    {
        DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Now;
        //Console.WriteLine("[{0:HH:mm:ss}] Doing {1}..", DateTime.Now, symbol);
        Console.WriteLine("Date and Time with Milliseconds: {0} doing {1}..",
               dateValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"), symbol);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to limit to 5/sec or 5 concurrent operations?

Comment: Yea, My major concern is the number of requests because my IP might be blocked if I step over the limit by the data provider for too long/frequent. As long as the system allows, threading is secondary.

Comment: Yes, it's a common constraint when dealing with external services. TPL Dataflow is perfect for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom task scheduler which limits the rate at which tasks can start.

In the below, tasks are queued up, and dequeued with a timer set to the frequency of your maximum allowed rate. So if 5 requests a second, the timer is set to 200ms. On the tick, a task is then dequeued and executed from those that are pending.

EDIT: In addition to the request rate, you can also extend to control the maximum number of executing threads as well.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(new LimitedExecutionRateTaskScheduler(5, 5)); // 5 per second, 5 max executing
    List<string> symbolsToCheck = new List<string>() { "GOOG", "AAPL", "MSFT" };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        symbolsToCheck.AddRange(symbolsToCheck);

    foreach (string symbol in symbolsToCheck)
    {
        factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0:HH:mm:ss}] [{1}] Doing {2}..", DateTime.Now, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, symbol);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("[{0:HH:mm:ss}] [{1}] {2} is done", DateTime.Now, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, symbol);
        });
    }

    Console.Read();
}


public class LimitedExecutionRateTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<Task> _pendingTasks = new ConcurrentQueue<Task>();            
    private readonly object _taskLocker = new object();
    private List<Task> _executingTasks = new List<Task>();
    private readonly int _maximumConcurrencyLevel = 5;
    private Timer _doWork = null;

    public LimitedExecutionRateTaskScheduler(double requestsPerSecond, int maximumDegreeOfParallelism)
    {
        _maximumConcurrencyLevel = maximumDegreeOfParallelism;
        long frequency = (long)(1000.0 / requestsPerSecond);
        _doWork = new Timer(ExecuteRequests, null, frequency, frequency);
    }

    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel
    {
        get
        {
            return _maximumConcurrencyLevel;
        }
    }

    protected override bool TryDequeue(Task task)
    {
        return base.TryDequeue(task);
    }
    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        _pendingTasks.Enqueue(task);
    }

    private void ExecuteRequests(object state)
    {
        Task queuedTask = null;
        int currentlyExecutingTasks = 0;

        lock (_taskLocker)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _executingTasks.Count; i++)
                if (_executingTasks[i].IsCompleted)
                    _executingTasks.RemoveAt(i--);

            currentlyExecutingTasks = _executingTasks.Count;
        }

        if (currentlyExecutingTasks == MaximumConcurrencyLevel)
            return;

        if (_pendingTasks.TryDequeue(out queuedTask) == false)
            return; // no work to do

        lock (_taskLocker)
            _executingTasks.Add(queuedTask);

        base.TryExecuteTask(queuedTask);
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return false; // not properly implemented just to complete the class
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        return new List<Task>(); // not properly implemented just to complete the class
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Steve, Thanks for the code. I will test this as well.

Comment: Steve's solution seems to set a limit of requests per sec. It works! As I need to keep updating all symbols during market hours, I think there still be need to keep the number of running threads under control.

Comment: @Shuang Liang, I've extended the example to allow you to limit the threads executing as well.

Comment: I don't know why it just loop once if I change the code like this

Comment: @Shuang Liang, You have a `Console.Read()` at the end of your loop.. press enter and it will continue.

Comment: Hi, Steve, every time I hit enter then it loops twice. Is it normal? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, as you're using `Console.Read()`, it reads character by character - enter is actually two characters, codes 10 (line feed) and 13 (carriage return). If you did `a`, then `enter`, that's three characters. Probably you want `Console.ReadKey()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a flow of url requests while limiting to no more than 5 concurrent operations you should use TPL Dataflow's `ActionBlock`:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<string>(
    url => requestFunc(url),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 });

foreach (var url in urls)
{
    block.Post(url);
}

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

You `Post` to it the urls and for each of them it would perform the request while making sure there are no more than `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` requests at a time.

When you are done, you can call `Complete` to signal the block for completion and `await` the `Completion` task to asynchronously wait until the block actually completes.

Comment: Hi, Good to know that. I will test this idea. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this does not enforce the 5 requests per second requirement

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd OP confirmed in the comments that this is not the actual requirement.

Comment: @I3arnon - hmmm, that is not how I interpret the comments but it is up to the OP to decide :)

Comment: I hear two voices. Hard to decide who is right. Let me take some time to test. I like to thank all of you for your inputs. I will post my vote later.

Answer (score 1):

Do not worry about the amount of threads; just make sure that you are not exceeding the number of requests per sec. Use a single timer to signal a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) every 200 ms and have the tasks wait for that ManualResetEvent inside a loop.

To create a timer and make it signal the ManualResetEvent every 200 ms:

```
resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
timer = new Timer((state)=>resetEvent.Set(), 200, 0);
```

Make sure you clean up the timer (call Dispose) when you do not need it anymore.

Let the number of threads be determined by the run-time.

This would be a poor implementation if you create a single task per stock because you do not know when a stock will be updated.

So you could just put all the stocks in a list and have a single task update each stock one after another.

By giving another list of stocks to another task you could give that task a higher priority by setting its timer to every 250 ms and the low priority to every 1000 ms. That would add up to 5 times a second and the high priority list would be updated 4 times more often than the low priority.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Actually, I plan to bundle 100 symbols (this seems to be the upper limit set by yahoo) in one query or task so that the total numbers of requests will be much lower, so as the number of requests/sec. I don't have a list of preferred stocks over others. My sole purpose is to update all in my list (about 1000), not all stocks in all markets, though. What is the syntax to do "signal a ManualResetEvent every 200 ms"? Thanks!

Comment: @ShuangLiang I added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop with a task delay to control when your requests are issued. Using an async void method to make your requests means you don't get blocked by a failing request.

Async void is fire and forget which some devs don't lkke but I think it would work as a possible solution in this case.

I also think erno de weerd makes a great suggestion around prioritising calls to more important stocks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @steve16351! It works like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LimitedExecutionRateTaskScheduler scheduler = new LimitedExecutionRateTaskScheduler(5);
        TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(scheduler);
        List<string> symbolsToCheck = new List<string>() { "GOOG", "AAPL", "MSFT", "AGIO", "MNK", "SPY", "EBAY", "INTC" };


        while (true)
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (string symbol in symbolsToCheck)
            {
                Task t = factory.StartNew(() => 
                {
                    write(symbol);
                }, CancellationToken.None, 
                   TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler);
                tasks.Add(t);
            } 
        } 
    }

    public static void write (string symbol)
    {
        DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Date and Time with Milliseconds: {0} doing {1}..",
               dateValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"), symbol);
    }
```